# How to use Nest.js SSE with AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nest

I tested my endpoint which is using Nest's SSE and it was successful on my local machine.

After deploying my Nest.js app to AWS Lambda, I see that the endpoint does not work on serverless.

I discovered the response streaming from AWS Lambda but didn't find any solution for my case.

Do you have any idea how to run streaming functions on AWS Lambda with Nest.js?

```
async sendMessage(dto: ChatDto): Promise\<Observable\<{ data: string }\>\> {
const configuration = {
apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
}
const openai = new OpenAI(configuration)

    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      (async () => {
        try {
          const responseStream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: dto.model,
            messages: dto.messages as any,
            stream: true,
          })
    
          for await (const chunk of responseStream) {
            const response = chunk.choices[0].delta.content;
            subscriber.next({ data: response })
          }
    
          subscriber.complete()
        } catch (error) {
          subscriber.error(error)
        }
      })()
    })

}
```

```
@UseGuards(JwtGuard, ApiKeyGuard) 
@Post("conversation") 
@Sse() 
sendMessage(@Body() dto: ChatDto) {   
  return this.service.sendMessage(dto) 
}
```

I need to fix my AWS Lambda issue using Nest.js.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using AWS Lambda response streaming. You could write your own Lambda handler (which would only work on Lambda, and nowhere else),  I haven't found anyone who got it working the "NestJS way".

Here's an example of a response stream lambda handler:

```
exports.handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(
    async (event, responseStream, context) => {
        responseStream.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        responseStream.write("event: test\n");
        responseStream.write('data: {"key": "value"}');
        responseStream.write('\n\n');
        responseStream.end();
    }
);
```

SSE is just a response stream with the MIME type text/event-stream. The format for named events is:

```
event: firstEvent
data: {...}

event: secondEvent
data: {...}

...
```

For your SSE NestJS controller to work, someone would need to make an adapter library - I haven't been able to found one that can handle the NestJS SSE implementation. Maybe you have just given me an idea.

For now, your best bet is probably to just separate that part of the application into its own Lambda function/handler instead of handling it in NestJS.

Keep in mind that, in reality, serverless really isn't meant for use cases like this and you might experience a lot more trouble than you would expect. I would really recommend moving away from Lambda for this use case and just using ECS/EC2 to handle this, you'd save yourself some time and headaches.